# Find Contacts - checkboxes not staying ticked in CiviCRM 5.15.1

Tags: contacts

CiviCRM 5.15.1
Joomla 3.9.8
PHP 7.2

When selecting contacts in the Find Contacts results page, if you tick a few of them, then go into one of them to edit it, then come out again, back to the search results, the ticks have disappeared. It used to remember the selection.

Has anyone else noticed this? It seems to have changed since upgrading to 5.15.1. Thanks.